# Half coloured boxplot in R

Tags: r, colors, plot, visualization, boxplot

Is there anyway to have the native R boxplot function produce boxplots with different colours for the top and bottom boxes? Something like this:

[image]

Here is the function I came up with:

```
h.boxplot <- function(..., col.top='orange', col.bottom='yellow', col.scheme='none'){
    cols = c(col.top, col.bottom)
    if(col.scheme != 'none'){
      cs =  list(blue=c('#0071c1', '#3198ff'), green=c('#008001', '#99cc00'), yellow=c('#ffcc00', '#cc9900'))
      stopifnot(col.scheme %in% names(cs))
      cols = cs[[col.scheme]]
    }

    bx<-boxplot(..., col = "white", lty=1, boxlwd=0.00001)
    n = length(bx$names)

    rect(1:n-.4, bx$stats[2,], 1:n+.4, bx$stats[3,], col=cols[2], border=NA)
    rect(1:n-.4, bx$stats[3,], 1:n+.4, bx$stats[4,], col=cols[1], border=NA)
    return(bx)
}

# Examples
data = list(A=1:10, B=20:50)
h.boxplot(data, col.scheme='green', outline=F, frame=F)
h.boxplot(data, col.scheme='blue', outline=F, frame=F)
```

Should give something like:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's not a parameter that you can set on the base `boxplot` function to get that behavior, but you can kind of fake it by drawing rectangles over the plot with different colors. For example

```
bx<-boxplot(count ~ spray, data = InsectSprays, col = "lightgray")
rect(1:6-.4, bx$stats[2,], 1:6+.4, bx$stats[3,], col="orange")
rect(1:6-.4, bx$stats[3,], 1:6+.4, bx$stats[4,], col="yellow")
```

[image]

You can continue to customize that however you like.

Comment: I was thinking exactly along those lines! Thank you! I will post my function for others soon.